# php - Sanitizing text input using HTMLPurifier - then redisplaying - apostrophe issue

Tags: php

I am using HTML_Purifier to sanitize user input. So sending the text to server in an ajax call, sanitizing it, storing it in the database, and then returning the sanitized string back to the browser to update on the screen. The problem I have, is the apostrophe is then prefixed with a backslash when displayed on the page.

```
 $DirtyText = $_POST["UserInput"]; //eg This is Brians's thoughts & comments

 $config = \HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
 $purifier = new \HTMLPurifier($config);
 $CleanText = $purifier->purify($DirtyText);
 
 // $CleanText now looks like : This is Brian\'s thoughts &amp; comments
 
 $this->UpdateDatabase($CleanText);       
 
 $obj = new \stdClass();
 $obj->CleanText = nl2br($CleanText);
 $obj->Result = 1;
 wp_send_json($obj);
```

Is it the right thing to do to just use stripslashes to remove the backslash when displaying?

This is in a Wordpress environment if there are any specific wp functions.

Comment: Why don't you try `str_replace` or `regex` to replace the `\'` ?

Comment: I know there are various ways to get rid of the slashes, but I was wondering if that is what I should be doing, or is there a built in function to prepare the string for display on a page - am I missing a trick, or does everybody just use a function to strip out the backslashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good to me, and there is no problem in using stripslashes($string). I did a simple search in wp developer refrence and found this:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/deslash/
and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_unslash/